# webClient.UploadValuesAsync not sending request

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5, webclient

I'm working on a MVC 5 web application.

I'm running jobs on a Quartz.Net job scheduler, trying to post the jobs progression on my web application to display progress bars.

The job part (the scheduler runs on the same machine) :

```
webClient = new WebClient
{
    CachePolicy = new System.Net.Cache.RequestCachePolicy(System.Net.Cache.RequestCacheLevel.NoCacheNoStore)
};

NameValueCollection values = new NameValueCollection();
values["JobId"] = this.jobId.ToString();
values["Progression"] = progression.Progression.ToString();
values["Status"] = progression.Status;
values["Description"] = progression.Description;

if (!webClient.IsBusy)
    webClient.UploadValuesAsync(new Uri("http://localhost/Report/SetProgression"), "POST", values);
```

This code executes without error, but for some reason, the `SetProgression` action from the `ReportController` is never called.

Moreover, a network traffic monitoring (Fiddler) never shows this request, like it was never sent by the web client.

Where could this behavior come from ? Am I missing something obvious ?

Comment: What do you do if `webClient.IsBusy` is true?

Comment: @usr It does nothing in this case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out:

By changing the `webClient.UploadValuesAsync` to its synchrone counterpart `webClient.UploadValues`, I got an internal server error from my web app.

That means that the request is correctly sent.

Doing this (thanks to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10733665/why-return-500-error-while-calling-another-controller-using-webclient#10734359)):

```
catch (WebException ex)
{
    using (var reader = new StreamReader(ex.Response.GetResponseStream()))
    {
        string responseText = reader.ReadToEnd();
    }
}
```

I was able to find the error and correct it.

The remaining mystery is why I can't see this request sending in Fiddler. Right now it doesn't matter, but out of curiosity, I'm open to enlightening suggestions.

Comment: Is the site running in IIS? IIS runs website under different users. Fiddler only auto-proxies the current user.

Comment: @usr Yes it runs in IIS. I guess that makes sense then. Thanks !